# ORACLE conditional COUNT query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
001 | 9441 | P021948  
001 | 9442 | P021948  
001 | 9443 | P021950  
001 | 9444 | P021951  
001 | 9445 | P021952  
001 | 9446 | P021948
```

In the above table I am looking to COUNT the third column so long as it is outside of the second column's value by (+/- 1).

In other words, I am trying to achieve a count of 2 for P021948 because values 9441 and 9442 are within 1 of each other and record 9446 is outside of that range.  My intent is to achieve a total count of 5 given these conditions.

How could I go about querying?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show exactly what your expected result set is for this example

Comment: @Grib . . . There are three values for "P021948".  Your question doesn't make sense.  What if the values were 9441, 9442, 9446, 9447, 9448 . . . what would be returned?

Comment: Please let me know if below answer works for you

Comment: Good point...I am trying to establish a relationship between the second and third column that would allow me to count the third so long as it is not the same for a deviation of 1 from the value in column 2.  Is that clear?

Comment: @GordonLinoff     If the value associated with P021948 are 9441,9442,9446,9447,9448 then I am trying to return a COUNT value of 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column3, 
sum(case when lag(column3, 1, 0) over(order by column3)=column3 or  
    lead(column3, 1, 0) over(order by column3)=column3 then 1 else 0 end)
from yourtable
        group by column1, column3
```

Comment: Any idea why I may be receiving a "window functions are not allowed here" error?

Comment: hmm not sure...try writing to a new table first using the window logic and then summing from there

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I'm thinking you want to count the "islands" that are separated by a value of more than 1.  If so:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, lag(col2) over (partition by col1, col3 order by col2) as prev_col2
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col2 is null or col2 - prev_col2 > 1;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/CQMQY78843) illustration of the query and the result.

Comment: Would you mind reformatting this query for me, considering the following column and table names.  I am unsure what I may be missing...

COLUMN 1 = C_MACHINE_NR
COLUMN 2 = C_SEQUENCE_NR
COLUMN 3 = C_PRODUCT

TABLE = HIS.T_HISJOBS

Comment: @Grib . . . Yes, I do mind.  You should describe the data in the *question* not in the *comments*.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for your time.